# Keras model optimization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to optimize my first AI with Google `colab` and `tensorflow`.

I have following `dataset` example:

| classification | Feature 1 | Feature 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1.1 | 0.22 |
| 1 | 0.333 | -0.4 |
| 4 | -0.55 | 0.6 |

- Classes are values from `1` to `4`. The dataset contains 50% of each.
- Values of the Features array are the Ratio between the real subject param and the average value

> Example: If each row is a student data. And `Feature 1` is the examination mark. Value `-0.1` means that current student's mark `10% less` than others (average).

Feature values could be greater than 1 (value 1.2 means +120%).

---

**The goal of my model is to find students who we should care about.**
So basically, I need to maximize the results for `true` predictions for classes 1 or 2. And prediction of classes 3 and 4 may not be as accurate.

> - It is preferable: if the real class is `1`, but the prediction is `3` - `4`
> - Rather than: real class `3` - `4` is was predicted as `1` or `2`

**I have the following model:**

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh', input_shape=(82, )),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=features, y=labels, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.33, epochs=1)
```

**My questions are:**

1. How can I configure metrics to calculate positive predictions for `class 1`
2. Should the number of output neurons be always the same value as the class amount? Does it make sense to have +1 neurons to accumulate 'noisy' data here to optimize classes `1` and `2` accuracy predictions?

Comment: I deleted your third question because it was too vague and not directly related to your question above. In such cases you risk the question being closed, as voted by the community.

Answer (score 0):

**For question 1**:

You want to maximize the TP for class_1 and class_2, regardless of potential "errors" (false positives in this case. It is recall you are interested in.

Because it's a multi-class classification problem and not a binary one, you cannot use the built-in metrics by default; you need to write a custom callback.

For example, a custom callback can be this one:

```
class MultiClassRecallCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, validation_data, average='macro', zero_division=0):
        super(MultiClassRecallCallback, self).__init__()
        self.validation_data = validation_data
        self.average = average
        self.zero_division = zero_division

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        val_x, val_y_true = self.validation_data
        #Here if you cannot predict everything at once,
        #make sure you do batch predictions and then flatten
        val_y_pred = np.argmax(self.model.predict(val_x), axis=1)
        
        recall = recall_score(val_y_true, val_y_pred, average=self.average, zero_division=self.zero_division)
        print(f'\nEpoch {epoch+1}: Recall is {recall}'

# The zero division is to put recall to 0 if there are no TP and FN
recall_callback = MultiClassRecallCallback(validation_data(X_val,y_val), average='macro', zero_division=0)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          epochs=50, callbacks=[recall_callback])
```

**For question 2**:

The number of neurons is always equal to the number of labels which you try to predict. If you believe that, for some data, there is a particular inherent noise, you can modify your dataset in which you add the fifth label in your example and assign those particular samples. This can indeed help your model better at distinguishing between your categories.

Comment: when I added `model.compile(... metrics=['accuracy', recall])` i started to get an error: `ValueError: Shapes (32, 4) and (32, 1) are incompatible` . all the rest params are the same

Comment: Yes, because it's a multiclass and not a binary classification problem. I will update Q1 asap.

Comment: 1) what is `validation_data(..)`  when I init `recall_callback` compiles says that `name 'validation_data' is not defined`. 2) does `X_val` and `y_val` should contain only `class_1` and `class_2` data?

Comment: 1) x=features, y=labels; you should split your dataset into X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, instead of full X and y for training; 2) No, X_val and y_val should contain ideally all the data, and then further on you can make some even more focused analysis on classes 1 and classes 2

Comment: @akozel did you manage to solve the problem or do you need more help in doing so?